# Instantiate a class (or derived) with internal constructor

Tags: c#

let's say I have a class defined in an assembly with:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    internal BaseClass()
    {
    }
}
```

And in another assembly, I would like to instanciate this class with :

```
BaseClass c = new BaseClass();
```

I get the CS0143 error.

Trying another way, I try to create a derived class of the first one :

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

but same error.

The BaseClass is not sealed. How can I instantiate this class or a derived one? Of course, I can't modify the BaseClass.

Comment: You can't new up since CTOR is `internal`, the `BaseClass` CTOR should be at least `protected`

Comment: Can you at least modify the project that builds the BaseClass? If so, take a look at the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Comment: no, i can't use internalstovisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection to get the internal constructor and invoke it:

```
var ci = typeof(BaseClass).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
var instance = (BaseClass)ci.Invoke(new object[0]);
```

Since the existence of the constructor is only discovered at run-time, this approach will break if the constructor of `BaseClass` is changed or removed.

Comment: While that's a possibility, it's unlikely that it's the appropriate solution here.  It's more likely that there is a factory class/method that the OP just hasn't found, or that the class is intended to be derived instead of constructed directly.

Comment: @Servy - There isn't enough information in the question to say.

Comment: True, which is why given all of the available options I would avoid suggesting the one that's both the least likely to be needed, and also the one with the greatest potential for abuse/misuse.  If the class intentionally prevented access to it's constructor then constructing one via reflection is likely to result in more problems down the road as you're fighting the design of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an System.MethodAccessException

Comment: @Tim - Then your code isn't sufficiently trusted to access the constructor through reflection. In that case there probably isn't a way to access the constructor.

Comment: too bad. and nothing I can do ?

Answer (score 1):

1) You want an actual instance of the base class:

There needs to be some method in the assembly that it's in that constructs it for you.  This would normally be called a "factory".  It might look like this:

```
public class BaseFactory
{
    public static BaseClass Create() { return new BaseClass(); } //may also add other creation logic
}
```

Note that such a creation method may even be in `BaseClass` itself, or it could be in another class.  (If the constructor was private it would need to be in the class itself.)

2) You want an instance of the derived class.  (Perhaps you're not *supposed* to be able to construct the base class.  If this is true it probably should be `abstract`.)

```
public class Derived : BaseClass {   }

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar() { Derived d = new Derived();}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question if `DerivedClass` is in the same assembly as `BaseClass`. If it is, just instantiate the derived class:

```
BaseClass c = new DerivedClass();
```

And, like Branko stated, if you have control of the project in which BaseClass lives, you can use [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).